# Which ruby version/build works best with rails 3?

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been having trouble discerning which version/build of ruby to use with the most recent rails 3 beta. I was using 1.8.7 but over time the server would use too much memory and begin to slow down and eventually not work at all. Which version/build worked best for you?

Answer (score 5):

Using 1.9.2 without any problems.
Had some issues with charsets and encodings with 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

We had problems with 1.8.7, so we shifted to 1.9.2 and we don't have any problems since.
Also 1.9 is faster, so I suggest to try with 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

1.9.1 is [reportedly](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-191-released-first-production-release-of-the-fastest-ruby-ever-1480.html) a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments at http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release/ mentions the following:

Ruby1.9 Users Before installing Rails 3, upgrade your system, i.e.,:

```
gem update --system
```

If you used `rubygems-update’ instead, then you might want to uninstall that first:

```
gem uninstall rubygems-update
gem update --system
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This problem bit me in the posterior, I had to downgrade from 1.9.1 to 1.8.7:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4414-rails3-segmentation-fault-remove_methodrb-when-you-have-a-library-module

Answer (score 0):

1.8.7 or 1.9.2
I'd recommend jruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced no issues running Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.2, but have noticed one particularly bad report running 35% faster.

Ruby 1.8.7

Run 1
Completed 200 OK in 20797ms (Views: 18662.2ms | ActiveRecord: 253.5ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Run 2
Completed 200 OK in 20300ms (Views: 18316.7ms | ActiveRecord: 312.1ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Run 3
Completed 200 OK in 19285ms (Views: 17309.8ms | ActiveRecord: 254.3ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Average: (20797 + 20300 + 19285)/3 = 20127

Ruby 1.9.2

Run 1
Completed 200 OK in 13499ms (Views: 11687.0ms | ActiveRecord: 273.6ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Run 2
Completed 200 OK in 12682ms (Views: 11176.2ms | ActiveRecord: 264.9ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Run 3
Completed 200 OK in 12692ms (Views: 11218.8ms | ActiveRecord: 253.0ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)

Average: (13499 + 12682 + 12692)/3 = 12958

(20127 - 12958) / 20127 = 35.6% reduction

Comment: Also worth noting that this same report runs twice as fast on Rails 2.3.8/Ruby 1.8.7 as it does on Rails 3.0.3/Ruby 1.8.7.